# How to tell QWebPage not to load images?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qwebpage

I'm using QWebPage to load needed site page. But QWebPage loading all additional resources: images, csses, and so on.
Is there any way to present this behavior and cancel loading of images?

Only idea that I have - to write custom QNetworkConnectionManager, which will return some dummy picture instead of requested. But this looks a bit of complicated.

Comment: If you would like to prevent loading specific type of images or load only specific type of images the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575245/how-to-tell-qwebpage-not-to-load-specific-type-of-resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to turn off the AutoLoadImages:

[http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qwebsettings.html](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qwebsettings.html)

Using the QWebSettings::AutoLoadImages attribute.