# How to tell QWebPage not to load specific type of resources?

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qnetworkaccessmanager, qwebpage

How to tell [`QWebPage`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwebpage.html) not to load specific type of resources like js, css or png?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The solution is to extend [`QNetworkAccessManager`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) class and override it's virtual method [`QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#createRequest) In our implementation we check the path of the requested url and if it's the one we don't want to download we create and hand over an empty request instead of the real one. 
Below is a complete, working example.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QUrl>

#include <QtWebKit/QWebPage>
#include <QtWebKit/QWebFrame>

#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
#include <QDebug>


class NAM : public QNetworkAccessManager {

    Q_OBJECT

protected:

    virtual QNetworkReply * createRequest(Operation op,
                                          const QNetworkRequest & req,
                                          QIODevice * outgoingData = 0) {

        if (req.url().path().endsWith("css")) {
            qDebug() << "skipping " << req.url();
            return QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(QNetworkAccessManager::GetOperation,
                                                        QNetworkRequest(QUrl()));
        } else {
            return QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(op, req, outgoingData);
        }
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWebPage page;
    NAM nam;

    page.setNetworkAccessManager(&nam);
    page.mainFrame()->load(QUrl("http://google.com"));

    app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Is there a way to check not by extension but by content type?

Comment: @Zelid Yes. See `QNetworkRequest::header()` and `QNetworkReply::header()`

Comment: Since Qt droped webkit and now uses chromium, QtWebEngine and QtWebView do not interact with QNetworkAccessManager any more: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html#qt-webengine-does-not-interact-with-qnetworkaccessmanager

Answer (score 0):

I am actually struggling with the same problem, Piotr solution is assuming urls with file extensions, unfortunately this is not always the case.

it is possible toe get mime-type but only after we get the response' and this is offcore to late.

we tried to get the element context requesting the resources, say if it is an `<img>` element or `<link>` to get CSS,  but `req.originatingObject()`
only gives us a **QWebFrame**.
i know for example that this was possible in mozilla code.

BTW, turning off **javascript** and **auto load images** will prevent loading of images and scripts.

Comment: You could try making a HEAD request just to get headers so that you can check Content-Type header and make decision based on its value.

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to prevent the Webpage from changing, you can take a look at

`virtual bool acceptNavigationRequest(QWebFrame *frame, const QNetworkRequest &request, NavigationType type);`

in QWebPage. You can inspect the request and return `false` if you want to prevent the request from being sent.

Comment: This is wrong for the same reason hmuelner's answer is wrong. From the [docs](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#acceptNavigationRequest) *This function is called whenever WebKit requests to **navigate** frame to the resource specified by request by means of the specified navigation type type.*