# interrupt request in createRequest method of QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have subclass of QNetworkAccessManager. I overridden createRequest method there. What to do inside if I want to return from that method and stop request? If I return 0, I get "segmantation fault"

Comment: I found solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575245/how-to-tell-qwebpage-not-to-load-specific-type-of-resources

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend QNetworkReply and return an instance of your customized Reply, implementing the pure virtual functions, which may do nothing inside in your case.